# TCPDF: In a single document, using multiple page formats, it doesn't print out on correct paper

Tags: tcpdf

I'm creating a document that consists of an 8.5"x11" survey, a #10 envelope and a #9 return-envelope. I use the appropriate AddPage calls and the resulting PDF appears to have all of the correct formatting.

When I print it, though, *every* page only comes out on 8.5"x11" paper...

Is there something in particular that I need to be doing to enable multiple page formats in a single document?

Answer (score 0):

So, it appears that this is an issue with each particular reader/viewer, where, as far as I can tell, the end user is required, on a case by case basis, to manually override using the default paper size and tell the print engine to use the paper size(s) specified by the document instead. It's frustrating that this wouldn't be the default configuration, but this appears to be the only solution that I could find.